# How to remove meta keywords tag from a specific page in joomla 2.5

Tags: jquery, joomla

How can I remove meta keywords tag from a specific page in joomla 2.5. I need to eliminate it from one page. However, it will be remained on the other pages as it is. I have tried using jQuery remove() function but it did not work.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function(){
                   jQuery("meta[name='keywords']").remove(); 
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: why not assign a class to meta tags and remove them ?

Comment: Meta tag will be removed using this but changes wont appear as meta tag has already played its part. something like this should not be done on page load.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setMetaData('keywords', "");
$document->setMetaData('robots', "");
$document->setMetaData('author', "");
```

For more details [about set meta data of Joomla Page](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-set-meta-data-of-a-page-in-joomla).

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove meta tags by setting its contents to a blank string through the JDocument class.

For example:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData('description', '');
```

This will remove the `<meta name="description" ... >` tag.

If you have access to the index.php of your chosen template, you can use the function setMetaData directly from $this:

```
$this->setMetaData('description', '');
```

If you are interested, see the Joomla! API documentation (search for JDocument and then for setMetaData): http://doc.joomladev.eu/api25/

Comment: I have tried it previously. However, it does not work on my expectation.

Comment: What's your expectation?

Comment: My expectation is to remove the meta 'keywords' from a specific joomla page. However, $doc->setMetaData('keywords', '') does not work for me. @FlavioEscobar

Comment: Another alternative is to omit the `<jdoc:include type="head" />` in the page you want. But you'll need to include all script, css etc. manually.